# how to create s.th. like a output stream in a function in java?

Tags: java

I want to solve the following problem:
I have a GUI class with some `JTextArea`. And I'm also writing my own class, lets call it `Foo`.

Actually, I have all my calculations in the GUI class. They just use s.th. like `myText.append(...)` to write some output into the GUI.

Now I want to put all the calculations into my new class `Foo`. **The problem**: How can I create a method, which get the `JTextArea` from the GUI as a input and then just use it as before to write some output text into it. I don't want to have this as a return value of the method!

Is this possible?

Comment: Question is unclear. Please show some code.

Comment: this is event-related if i got the question right, you want once you click/press enter that the current picture will be saved(or text for that matter) - so you need someone to listen to the enter/click.

Comment: @mtk: Question is not unclear. English just isn't his native language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this...

```
public class Foo {
    public void writeInfoToTextArea(JTextArea textArea /*, other parms here */) {
        textArea.setText(...);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a mapper or adapter, i.e. something that accepts the methods from one interface and translates them into method calls of another interface. In your case, I suggest to use `Writer` over `OutputStream` to avoid all the encoding issues. Try this code:

```
public Foo extends Writer {
    private JTextArea textArea;

    public Foo( JTextArea textArea ) {
        this.textArea = textArea;
    }

    public void write(char cbuf[], int off, int len) throws IOException {
        String text = new String( cbuff, off, len );
        textArea.append( text );
    }

    public void close() { }
    public void flush() { }
}
```

If you really need an `OutputStream`, have a look at `OutputStreamWriter` to convert between bytes and Unicode characters.